# how to implement gamecenter in iphone game 

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

i want to add gamecenter in my app to share player score on the game center .. any help ?
regards
Haseeb

Comment: Read the documentation. Google around for blogs and tutorials on the subject. Come back here when you get stuck on something specific.

Comment: i have read all stuff but i didnt get any think which can realy help me out .. thats y  m here ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read "[Learn iPhone and iPad cocos2d Game Development](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039)"? Chapter-14 'Game Center' is a quite good tutorial for using Game Center.

Comment: @kazuki
while following this book method .. getting this error

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameKitHelper", referenced from:

Comment: Undefined symbols:
  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameKitHelper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-GameKitHelper in BlocksParty.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Download the demo project from [Game Kit Data Send/Receive Demo Project](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/01/game-kit-data-sendreceive-demo-project/) and copy Classes/GameKitHelper.h,m.

Comment: that problem is solve ... noew when in my gameclass when i call 

 GameKitHelper *gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
its giving this error

+[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Comment: thankx man i am following this samplecode.. if any prblem come then let you know...

Comment: @kazuki sakamoto

thanks its working goodd..... now just help me .. i want as game is over the score of the play is submit auto if the user is sign in ...
any idea

Comment: @kazuki using this method to submir score ... but some its onle submit score some times
-(void) submitScore:(int64_t)score category:(NSString*)category
{
 if (isGameCenterAvailable == NO)
  return;
 
 GKScore* gkScore = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
 gkScore.value = score;
 
 [gkScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError* error)
  {
   [self setLastError:error];
   
   bool success = (error == nil);
   [delegate onScoresSubmitted:success];
  }];
}

Comment: whats ur current problem?? i use gamecenter and its works fine